# Formula for mana gain (MP), need help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to think of a formula for this video game scenario:

Every time you level, you gain a base rate of 20 mana points (MP) from that levelup. Afterwards, you also gain 5 points of INT (intelligence).

Every 10 points of INT gives you 1 extra point of MP on levelup (INT rounded down).

E.g.

START:
Level 1
4 INT
100 MP

LEVELUP:
Lvl 1 (4 INT) -> Lvl 2
MP gain = 0 bonus + 20 base MP = +20 MP
Total MP = 120

Lvl 2 (now 9 INT) -> Lvl 3
MP gain = 0 bonus + 20 base MP = +20 MP
Total MP = 140

Lvl 3 (now 14 INT) -> Lvl 4
MP gain = 1 bonus + 20 base MP = +21 MP
Total MP = 161

Lvl 4 (now 19 INT) -> Lvl 5
MP gain = 1 bonus + 20 base MP = +21 MP
Total MP = 182

Lvl 5 (now 24 INT) -> Lvl 6
MP gain = 2 bonus + 20 base MP = +22 MP
Total MP = 204

In words, if I am Lvl 1 with 4 INT and I level to Lvl 2, from that levelup I will gain 20 MP (0 bonus + 20 base MP). The 5 INT points then get added and I now have 9 INT.

If I then level again from Lvl 2-3, I will still only gain 20 MP (0 bonus + 20 base), because I still only have 9 INT at time of levelup.

From this levelup, I then get another 5 INT for a total of 14 INT. Thus when I level from Lvl 3-4, I gain 21 MP (1 bonus + 20 base).

Is there a way to calculate how much total MP I will have at level 130, when starting from level 1? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: What is a "mana point " ?

Answer (score 1):

INT at level $n$ $=5n-1$

So bonus mana levelling up from $n$ to $n+1$ is $\lfloor \frac{5n-1}{10} \rfloor$

Which turns out equal to $\frac{n-1}{2}$ is $n$ is odd and $\frac{n-2}{2}$ is $n$ is even.

As the increment depends on if $n$ is odd or even, things will be eaier if we consider the mana it takes to level up twice instead- then we only have one formula to worry about.

If $n$ is odd, levelling up from $n$ to $n+2$ gives $\frac{n-1}{2} +\frac{n+1-2}{2} = n-1 $

So to calculate the total bonus mana levelling up from $1$ to $ 1+2k$ we add up $n-1$ for all odd $n$ up to $1+2k$, which is
$$0 + 2 + \dots + 2(k-1)$$

This is $2$ times the $n-1$th triangular number, which is $2 \times \frac{1}{2}k(k-1) = k(k-1)$.

So the total bonus mana levelling up from 1 to 29 is ($k=14$ so) $14\times 13$.

This means the total mana going from 1 to 29 is $28 \times 20 + 14 \times 13$. You have to deal with the extra level separately.

The extra level gives you $34$ for a total of

$$28 \times 20 + 14 \times 13 + 34 = 776$$